# Are Objective-C Objects Pass By Value or Pass By Reference?

Tags: objective-c, object, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

So I have something like :

```
- (void) printString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}


NSString *string = @"Blach";
[self printString:string];
```

Would `string` be passed in by value or reference? What about something like NSError?

```
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:someDomain 
                                     code:-101 
                                 userInfo:someInfo];

-(NSString *) doSomething:(BOOL) val withError:(NSError **)error {
    if(!val)
    {
       *errorPtr = [NSError errorWithDomain:something
                                       code:-101 
                                   userInfo:someInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should know from your foundational knowledge of C that Objective-C *objects* are passed by *reference*.  If you don't know C then you shouldn't be mucking with Objective-C.

Comment: @HotLicks The fundamentals of C don't teach anything about how Objective-C objects (or any other Objective-C specific features) behave. The only thing C teaches (in relation to this question) is that object *pointers* are passed by value (like all parameters).

Answer (score 5):

You can *never* refer to an Objective-C object by anything other than a pointer, so for all intents and purposes, everything is pass-by-reference. That said, the actual pointer values are passed by value, just like in C.

Comment: Intents?? :P. What is intent in iOS scope??

Answer (score 1):

Everything of every type in Objective-C is **pass-by-value only**.

The question is invalid because "objects" are not values in Objective-C and therefore cannot be "passed" -- you cannot have a variable or expression whose value "is an object" (a bare object type is not allowed in the language) -- instead, "objects" must always be manipulated behind pointers to objects. Since "objects" are not values and you cannot "pass" them, it is meaningless to ask about whether they are "pass-by-value" or "pass-by-reference".

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference. The important distinction, to my mind, is whether the called method has a reference to the same object as the caller or if it has a copy. It has a reference to the same object.

If the object is mutable and the called method mutates it, it affects the object that the caller has, too (because it's the same object).

In the case of an `NSError**` parameter, it is actually the *pointer* (not an object) which is being passed by reference. A method with such a parameter can actually modify the caller's pointer, making it point to a different object.